In which situations is it okay to exceptionally prefix いち/一 to powers of 10 (ten) which are not powers of 10000 (ten thousand)?
My textbook (みんなの日本語, 2e, TWnese edition by 大新書局) and teacher teach that いち/一 is added for powers of 10000 (ten thousand), but not for other powers of 10 (ten). (That's not exactly how they phrase it, but this is the generalization I'm extracting from what they state.)



numeral
kana (pitch accent: ꜜ￫)
kanji
English (citation form)




1
いちꜜ
一
one


10
じゅꜜう
十
ten


100
ひゃくꜜ
百
hundred


1000
せꜜん
千
thousand


1,0000
いちまꜜん
一万
ten thousand


10,0000
じゅうまꜜん
十万
hundred thousand


100,0000
ひゃくまꜜん
百万
million


1000,0000
せんまꜜんfn
千万
ten million


1,0000,0000
いちꜜおく
一億
hundred million



fn The textbook (p161) really shows せんまん (千万), not いっせんまん (一千万). Some users tell me that the latter is what people prefer.
I asked my teacher whether one can add いち/一 in the other cases (powers of 10 which are not powers of 10000), and he replied that, yes, sometimes people will say things like いっせん/一千 for clarity, such as when discussing money, perhaps in a store or for a bank check. My questions:

When exactly can 一 (いち/いっ/similar) be added before number-initial 十/百/千? (= When does it not sound wrong?)
When is it customarily added? (= When would or might people actually do this?)
What would be the pitch accent in those cases?

Here are some related questions, which don't address my point:

Why should not put 一 before 千,百,十, but ok for 万? (assumes my table as the rule and asks for rationale)
Prefixing `一` to numbers (asks for rationale for (一)千)
Confusion about 一千億 and 一千兆 (only discussion of (一)千)


I'm confused about what you're asking about.  Your linked answered seem to answer the question you've posted here.  Perhaps you can explain what they've not answered.  Otherwise, it looks like you've merely pointed out duplicates to your own question.

The question about pitch accent would properly be better as its own separate question so as not to get muddled with tangential questions.

@A.Ellett The other posts express uncertainty about what the general rule is and ask about what it is and about its rationale. My post assumes a specific rule as the default, doesn't ask about the rationale, and asks about specific exceptions. (Also: My post contains a really nice table :-P)

@A.Ellett I understand your point about pitch accent – but I don't yet know which patterns exist. (Is 一十 ever legal?) Also, in a sense, one can argue that pitch accent should be part of an answer, just like an IPA transcription might be part of an answer about an English word. I guess I could later ask a separate question, but: (1) let's first wait, and (2) the answers are probably simple. That said, I will accept answers as correct if they don't discuss pitch accent at all.

@A.Ellett As a linguist and hobby lexicographer I'm generally interested in majority usage (and in "significant minority" usage). In this case, I would like someone to put more meat on the statement by my teacher.

I haven't met anyone who says せんまん for 1000,0000 as your nice table suggests. Everyone, myself included, says いっせんまん.

The situation is completely different for 10/100 and for 1000.
いちじゅう【LHLLL】 and いっぴゃく【LLHHH】 are jargon used only in special contexts, and laypeople never use it. When you do have a reason to use it, you may want to pronounce 2 as ふた, too. See my previous answer for details. Winning numbers of a lottery used to be announced like ふたせんいっぴゃくいちじゅうふた in the past, and this was when I learned something like いちじゅう is okay in special situations. However, this practice seems to have been discontinued, and they pronounce numbers simply like にせんひゃくじゅうに in this recent video. Again, this is a special convention in some industries, and many native speakers may not even know this.
1000 is tricky. It's almost always いっせん when it directly comes before まん for some reason. In other contexts, せん and いっせん【LLHL】 are both common and are basically interchangeable. In my experience, the default choice is せん in everyday shopping or such, but いっせん are often chosen in the following situations:

When numbers need to be conveyed accurately or digit-by-digit, such as on the phone or in math problems
When the number is precisely 1000 and saying only せん sounds a bit too short. For example, many people (unconsciously) read 1000m as いっせんメートル but 1100m as せんひゃくメートル.


Is [いっぴゃく]{LLHHH} heiban or odaka ([いっぴゃく(は)]{LLHHHLLL}), or would the distinction not make sense for this lexical item?

@LoverofStructure It's rarely followed by a particle, but my intuition says it's odaka...

Do laypeople not use いちじゅう and いっぴゃく for contrastive emphasis? I know that their equivalents are not uncommonly used that way in Chinese, for instance. “にじゅうさんですか?” — “違います、いちじゅうさんです!”.

@JanusBahsJacquet Most people never do that at all. I wouldn't be surprised if a few people come up with it after failing to convey the number many times, though.
